# calling write() over ssh

Tags: c, linux, file, ssh

I wrote the following code on a host called `node00` and save as `main.c`.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
        int fd;
        const char str[300]="hello world\n";
        fd = open("NOTE", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);

        if(fd != 0){

                write(fd, str, sizeof(str));
                close(fd);
                puts("succ");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Then, I compiled it to `main`.
After that, I run `ssh node00 TEST/main` on another machine, but the file `NOTE` does not exist in the `node00`, although I run `./main` on the `node00`, finding the file `NOTE` containing `hello world`.

I would ask you to give me an idea to run the program as expected.

Thank you guys for all comments and answers, in advance.

Comment: `NOTE` will be at `node00` `TEST/NOTE` after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your command through SSH like that, the working directory will be your home on `node00` so the `NOTE` file will be created in the parent directory of the  `TEST` directory.

If you want `NOTE` to be created alongside the `main` file in the `TEST` directory, you can try something like

```
ssh node00 "cd TEST && ./main"
```